# START/STOP VirtualBox VM when the Host boots or shuts down

Tags: windows-10, boot, virtualbox, shutdown, automation

I have been searching for a way to auto start and stop a vm when the machine boots or shuts down.

I found several ways to start it using Task Scheduler but no ways to shut it down when the host goes down.

Is there a way to do both effectively, or should I just need to remember that I have to manually start and stop them?